# KnockoutJS read viewmodel from local file?

Tags: java, javascript, knockout.js

I'm writing a client-server framework in Java, and I want the server to display some metrics on a HTML page.

To do this, I would love to be able to use KnockoutJS (very little experience) so that the server can update the metrics values and the HTML page can reflect the changes instantly and without needing to refresh the page.

Is it possible to have a local viewmodel (that is updated by the Java program) read by Knockout? Or is there a better solution for the problem?

Comment: For real time updates you might want to check out meteor.js rather than knockout.js. Meteor does live updates natively.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Atmosphere](http://async-io.org/) which has [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) like capability to push data down to a web browser, RPC style.

And then on the client/Javascript application side you can wire up your atmosphere callbacks to update the observable properties (the one(s) representing your metrics) on the knockout viewmodel bound to your web page.

This [blog post](http://baljeetsandhu.wordpress.com/2013/06/04/real-world-knockout-js/) describes implementing similar features.